# VueJS "this" is undefined

Tags: vue.js, supabase

So i'm having a problem here is that i'm trying to store the data requested on my database on a variable "history" in the data object
But i'm getting "this is undefined"

```
export default {
setup () {
    const loading = ref(true);
    const user = supabase.auth.user();

    async function getHistory() {
        try {
            loading.value = true;
                let { data, error, status } = await supabase
                .from("history")
                .select(`user_id, title`)
                .eq("user_id", user.id)
                .single()

                if (error && status !== 406) throw error

                if (data) {
                this.history = data
                }
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error.message)
            } finally {
                loading.value = false
        }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
        getHistory()
    })
     
    return {
        loading,
        user,
        history,
    }
},

data() {
    return {
        history: []
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` cannot be referenced inside the setup function. You can declare `history` as a stateful var inside the same setup fn. as `const history = ref([])` and use it inside just as a variable and return it at the last. Then you can reference the `history` var outside of the setup fn. as `this.history.value`

Comment: probably because there is no this in arrow functions - for that you need the function keyword. im not sure how it works in modules though, that is probably the issue as it just worked for me in a normal script

Comment: Thanks it worked i needed to use ref not the data object

Answer (score 1):

```
export default {
  setup(props, context) {
    // this cannot be referenced here, because yet the component is not set up
    // here we can declare reactive vars and use them anywhere from the component
    const history = ref([])


    function getHistory() {
      // here we reference history just as a reactive variable.
      history.value = ['1']
    }


    onMounted(() => {
      getHistory()
    })

    return { history }
  },
  computed: {
    logHistory() {
      // outside of the setup fn. we can use the `this` op. to reference state vars.
      console.log(this.history.value)
    }
  }
}
```